# Calling String in Bean Class Returns Null

Tags: java, android

I have a bean class that successfully retrieves a string value from another class.= (It prints it just fine within the bean class)

When I try and call that class/string it returns as null.

Here is the relevant code:

```
 public class cityModel implements Serializable {
    private String fajr;

    public void setFajr(String fajr) {
        this.fajr= fajr;

    }
    public String getFajr() {

        return fajr;
    }
}
 public void mutePrayerTime(View view) {
    cityModel cityObj= new cityModel();
    String fajr=cityObj.getFajr();
    Log.d("LOGCAT", "" + cityObj.getFajr());

    //StringBuilder newFajr = new StringBuilder(fajr);
    //newFajr.delete(2,5);
    //Log.d("newFajr", String.valueOf(newFajr));
  //  Intent alarm = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);

   //alarm.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, fajr );

}
```

the Log.d tag LOGCAT returns as null

edit:
Code that the bean class retrieves the string from:

```
  protected void outputTimings(JSONArray jsonArray) {
        String[] prayers = {"fajr", "shurooq", "dhuhr", "asr", "maghrib", "isha"};
        cityModel cityObj;
        try {
            cityObj= new cityModel();
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject cityObject =
                        jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                result = result + "fajr" + " : "
                        + cityObject.getString("fajr") + "\n" + result + "shurooq" + " : "
                        + cityObject.getString("shurooq") + "\n" + result + "dhuhr" + " : "
                        + cityObject.getString("dhuhr") + "\n" + result + "asr" + " : "
                        + cityObject.getString("asr") + "\n" + result + "maghrib" + " : "
                        + cityObject.getString("maghrib") + "\n" + result + "isha" + " : "
                        + cityObject.getString("isha") + "\n";

                cityObj.setFajr(""+cityObject.getString("fajr"));


            }
```

Comment: Doesn't look like the above code would even compile. `fajr` is a String and you're trying to invoke it as if it's a method like so `fajr()`. Do you also have a method with the same name? Post its code.

Comment: It compiles and runs. Ill add the code to the main post

Comment: Post full code of the class where `mutePrayerTime` method is defined.

Comment: updated it will the entire mutePrayerTime definition

Answer (score 1):

Have a look in this method:

```
public void mutePrayerTime(View view) {
    cityModel cityObj= new cityModel();
    String fajr=cityObj.getFajr();
    Log.d("LOGCAT", "" + cityObj.getFajr());

    //StringBuilder newFajr = new StringBuilder(fajr);
    //newFajr.delete(2,5);
    //Log.d("newFajr", String.valueOf(newFajr));
  //  Intent alarm = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);

   //alarm.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, fajr );

}
```

You're just creating cityObj like this `cityModel cityObj= new cityModel();` at that point all its properties are `null` that's why you're seeing null in your log. You should pass the `cityObj` from your `outputTimings` method to the `mutePrayerTime` method:

```
public void mutePrayerTime(View view,cityModel cityObj) {
    Log.d("LOGCAT", "" + cityObj.getFajr());

    //StringBuilder newFajr = new StringBuilder(fajr);
    //newFajr.delete(2,5);
    //Log.d("newFajr", String.valueOf(newFajr));
    //  Intent alarm = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);

   //alarm.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, fajr );

}
```

and then in `outputTimings`:

```
cityObj.setFajr(""+cityObject.getString("fajr"));
someObj.mutePrayerTime(view, cityObj);
```

Comment: Ahhh!! Makes a lot more sense. Thanks!

Comment: just so I can understand better, whats the purpose of the second obj in outputTimings and where/how should it be defined?

Comment: It's where ever your `mutePrayerTimings` method is. @Fencer300

Comment: thanks for helping me with this, still grasping the idea. I understand that the way i defined it returned the string as null, but I don't understand the reason behind _someobj_, can you explain its purpose to me?

Comment: Can you go to the file where mutePrayerTimings is and tell me what the name of that file is? It must be in a class. So someObj is an instance of that class. You MUST HAVE created it somewhere when you're calling that method.

Comment: I didn't create it anywhere else. The only other place it is located is in my activity_main.xml in the android:OnClick property

Comment: yeah only in the activity main